# langchain + Weaviate how to access multiple columns at once

Tags: python, langchain, weaviate, large-language-model

I have created a schema with multiple properties in Weaviate. using the following approach:

```
for row in tqdm(data, total=len(data)):
            client.data_object.create(data_object=row, class_name=INDEX_NAME)
```

here is a sample of the data (1 row):

```
{'Table_Name': 'Cust', 'Column_Name': 'Amount', 'Data_Type': 'Number', 'Table_Description': 'customer table', 'Column_Description': 'total transaction amount'}
```

How can langchain access multiple keys object (see example above) via the Weaviate() class?

```
 vectorstore = Weaviate(weaviate_client, INDEX_NAME, <??>)
```

when not passing the third argument to get all the objects, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/main.py", line 43, in <module>
    vectorstore = populate_data(weaviate_client)
  File "/Users/main.py", line 39, in populate_data
    return Weaviate(weaviate_client, INDEX_NAME)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text_key'
```

Answer (score 1):

LangChain only supports passing 1 property. This property is meant to represent the document's text content that will be used for embeding & search.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. do you know any alternate solution where I can search on multiple columns?

Comment: how about create n vectorstores, 1 for each property and then figure out a way to map reduce the search across the vectorstores? I think this is easier to be done with llama index.

Or just use the weaviate client directly to do the saerch queries 